# Fetch Domain name of UPN alias

Tags: java, groovy, ldap

Need a help in LDAP.

I have created an UPN alias testServer.ad for domain demo.com in active directory.

Now how do i fetch domain from UPN alias, from code base.

Any help on this!

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.